# Oracle PLSQL validate a row and insert each cell value of row as a new row with validation results in another table oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am very much new to the DB world, so wanted to review whether I am following right approach or not.
I have two tables,

table A  --> is a table with 40 columns

table B --> is a table with the 3 columns (each column of table A is represented as a row in this table.)

Example:

```
A:
column_1    |      column_2          |    column_3 ......... | column_40 
-----------------------------------------------------------
value1_1    |      value1_2          | value1_3......        | value1_40


B:
column_name      |column_value  | column_errorKey
----------------------------------------------------
column_1         | value1_1     | value1_1_errorKey
column_2         | value1_2     | value1_2_errorKey
```

What am I doing?

Validate each value of a row from table A and insert into the table B with 
 its value, error key and corresponding column name.

My PL SQL code is as below, (Note: SQL code has considered only two columns to minimize the code here)

```
INSERT WHEN  (LENGTH(column_1)  <=7) THEN
        into table_B values(
          'column_1',column_1,'NoError')
WHEN  (LENGTH(column_1)  >7) THEN
        into table_B values(
          'column_1',column_1,'invalidLength')
WHEN  (LENGTH(column_2)  <= 75) THEN
        into table_B values(
          'column_2',column_2,'NoError')
WHEN  (LENGTH(column_2)  > 75) THEN
        into table_B values(
          'column_2',column_2,'invalidLength')
( select column_1,column_2,...,column_40
          from table_A );
```

The validation that is happening within When the condition has only one validation but we have more validation like this for the value of each cell. I wanted to know whether I am on right approach or not.

Comment: crosspost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839473/oracle-plsql-validate-a-row-and-insert-each-cell-value-of-row-as-a-new-row-with

Answer (score 1):

We know that it is best when a single SQL statement can be written for solving a problem.  However, your situation requires a SQL statement that would be very unwieldy and difficult to debug and test.  One of your comments* contains the following facts:

> User can enter anything between 0 to 1000 characters (Data is read
>   from the excel, and end user do not want any restriction on the
>   excel). But on our application, we have to show the errors of the
>   excel.

(* see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839473/oracle-plsql-validate-a-row-and-insert-each-cell-value-of-row-as-a-new-row-with )

My suggestions are: {1} Create a table ("checks") that contains all necessary conditions (checks) including error messages, comments etc. {2} Using PL/SQL and BULK COLLECT to read all rows from this table, and subsequently generate dynamic SQL statements that perform batches of tests (checks) and write their results to a log table (your "table B").

**{1}**

```
create table checks (
  condition varchar2(256)
, colname varchar2(256)
, errmessage varchar2(256) default 'no error'
);

begin
insert into checks ( condition, colname ) values ( 'LENGTH( column_1 ) <= 7', 'column_1') ;
insert into checks ( condition, colname ) values ( 'LENGTH( column_2 ) <= 75', 'column_2') ;
insert into checks ( condition, colname ) values ( 'LENGTH( column_3 ) <= 17', 'column_3') ;
insert into checks ( condition, colname ) values ( 'LENGTH( column_4 ) <= 17', 'column_4') ;
-- etc
-- etc
-- etc
insert into checks ( condition, colname, errmessage ) 
values ( 'LENGTH( column_38 ) > 44', 'column_38', 'invalid length' ) ;
insert into checks ( condition, colname, errmessage ) 
values ( 'LENGTH( column_39 ) > 44', 'column_39', 'invalid length' ) ;
insert into checks ( condition, colname, errmessage ) 
values ( 'LENGTH( column_40 ) > 44', 'column_40', 'invalid length' ) ;
end;
/
```

**{2}**

```
declare
  type checks_t is table of checks%rowtype ;
  tchecks checks_t ;
  sqlstring   varchar2(1000) := '' ;
begin
  select condition, colname, errmessage 
  bulk collect into tchecks
  from checks ;

  for i in tchecks.first .. tchecks.last
  loop
    sqlstring := 'insert into b ( column_name, column_value, column_errorKey ) '
              || 'select '
              || ' ( select ''' || tchecks( i ).colname || ''' from dual ), '
              || 'substr( ' 
              ||  tchecks( i ).colname || ', 1, 256 ) ,'
              || ' case '
              || ' when ' || tchecks( i ).condition
              || ' then ''' || tchecks( i ).errmessage
              || ''' else ''condition evaluates to FALSE'' end '
              || ' from A' ;
    execute immediate sqlstring ;
    sqlstring := '' ;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

There is quite a lot of example code in the [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=992fea17cfeef807bae1e7c45c083b07).  However,  the first 5 sections are just about test data for "table A", which is supposed to resemble data stored in the spreadsheet (40 columns x 16 rows).  With this setup, table B will end up having 1280 rows after the PL/SQL anonymous block has been executed (80 checks are run on each row of table A).

Being a bit wary about the performance of the script, I've done some testing on a smallish VM (Oracle 12c).
Results as follows:

```
-- table A with 50 rows -> 4000 generated INSERTs into B (80 checks per row)
-- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.050

-- table A with 234256 rows -> 18740480 generated INSERTs into B
-- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:02:18.305

SQL> select count(*) from B;
COUNT(*)  
18740480 

Elapsed: 00:00:25.945
```

Due to limitations of Oracle 11g (no identity columns) and dbfiddle (could not create a sequence), there are no ID columns or PK constraints anywhere in this example.  Also, the error messages (in the checks table) can be a bit misleading, but all that can be "easily" adjusted .

Comment: If dbfiddle doesnt support something you want tk demonstrate, use http://LiveSQL.oracle.com for your examples.